# R function of returning all the outputs not the last one

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I have a function defined as:

```
foo<-function(data){
    for (i in 2:10)
    run.model<-mark(data[sample(nrow(data), i),], model="Occupancy")
    results<-data.frame(mean(summary(run.model)$real$p), summary(run.model)$real$Psi, i)
    return(results)
    }
```

"mark" is the function for running the model of my interest. However, the results only contain the last model where i=10

```
  mean.summary.run.model..real.p.        X1  i
1                       0.1403083 0.6414447 10
```

How do I correct my function so it compile results from i=2 to i=10?

---

(Can't answer my own question so I editted my question to show how I modified your codes:

Thank you both.

I modified @David Robinson 's codes

```
foo<-function(data){
    do.call(rbind, lapply(2:6, function(i){
        run.model<-mark(data[sample(nrow(data), i),], model="Occupancy")
        cbind(p=mean(summary(run.model)$real$p), Psi=summary(run.model)$real$Psi, stations=i)
        }))
    }
```

And got these outputs:

```
         p            1 stations
 0.4895234 1.388066e-10        2
 0.2902716 3.445050e-01        3
 0.0942734 7.955582e-01        4
 0.1683427 2.376106e-01        5
 0.1683427 1.980088e-01        6
```

I wonder why I named the second column but it did not appear in the output?

For @zzk 's codes I modified them as below:

```
foo<-function(data){
results.frame <- data.frame()
for (i in 2:6) {
    run.model<-mark(data[sample(nrow(data), i),], model="Occupancy")
    results<-data.frame(p=mean(summary(run.model)$real$p), Psi=summary(run.model)$real$Psi, stations=i)          
    results.frame <- rbind(results.frame, results)
    }
return(results.frame)
}
```

And the outputs:

```
          p           X1 stations
1 0.1683427 5.940264e-01        2
2 0.5533567 7.292506e-12        3
3 0.0500000 1.000000e+00        4
4 0.1683427 7.128317e-01        5
5 0.2321999 3.588861e-01        6
```

Pretty much the same.

The other questions are:
1. If I want to repeat this loop n time, I would like to use function "replicate". But I have no idea how to put it.
2. Is it possible to make the output as a data.frame so I can manipulate it later? (ex. calculate means, make graphs, grouping...etc)

---

I used
    replicate(10, foo(data))

Here is what I got. Looks like the output becomes problematic and the rows and columns are inverted. Same outcome with "replicate(100, foo(data), simplify="data.frame")".

```
         [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]      [,7]      [,8]      [,9]      [,10]    
p        Numeric,3 Numeric,3 Numeric,3 Numeric,3 Numeric,3 Numeric,3 Numeric,3 Numeric,3 Numeric,3 Numeric,3
X1       Numeric,3 Numeric,3 Numeric,3 Numeric,3 Numeric,3 Numeric,3 Numeric,3 Numeric,3 Numeric,3 Numeric,3
se.p     Numeric,3 Numeric,3 Numeric,3 Numeric,3 Numeric,3 Numeric,3 Numeric,3 Numeric,3 Numeric,3 Numeric,3
se.Psi   Numeric,3 Numeric,3 Numeric,3 Numeric,3 Numeric,3 Numeric,3 Numeric,3 Numeric,3 Numeric,3 Numeric,3
stations Integer,3 Integer,3 Integer,3 Integer,3 Integer,3 Integer,3 Integer,3 Integer,3 Integer,3 Integer,3
```

But if I use this code (with 1 more column in the output)

```
foo<-function(data){
do.call(rbind, lapply(2:4, function(i){
    run.model<-mark(data[sample(nrow(data), i),], model="Occupancy")
    cbind(mean(summary(run.model)$real$p), Psi=summary(run.model)$real$Psi, se.p=mean(summary(run.model, se=T)$real$p$se), stations=i)
    }))
}
```

With

```
replicate(5, foo(data))
```

I got

```
, , 1

                  1      se.p stations
 0.4895234 1.388066e-10 0.0000000        2
 0.0333333 1.000000e+00 0.0327731        3
 0.2117159 8.265795e-01 0.0833965        4

, , 2
.....
.....
, , 5

                   1      se.p stations
 0.2902716 0.5167575 0.1519857        2
 0.2000000 1.0000000 0.0730297        3
 0.2902716 0.2583787 0.1519857        4
```

With 
    replicate(5, foo(data), simplify="data.frame")

I got these.

```
             [,1]         [,2]         [,3]         [,4]      [,5]
 [1,] 4.895234e-01 1.683427e-01 4.895234e-01 1.683427e-01 0.1683427
 [2,] 1.683427e-01 5.533567e-01 2.902716e-01 5.533567e-01 0.0666667
 [3,] 2.500000e-02 2.117159e-01 2.321999e-01 3.974777e-01 0.0250000
 [4,] 1.388066e-10 5.940264e-01 1.388066e-10 5.940264e-01 0.5940264
 [5,] 3.960176e-01 7.292506e-12 3.445050e-01 7.292506e-12 1.0000000
 [6,] 1.000000e+00 8.265795e-01 5.383291e-01 2.515864e-01 1.0000000
 [7,] 0.000000e+00 1.379382e-01 0.000000e+00 1.379382e-01 0.1379382
 [8,] 1.379382e-01 0.000000e+00 1.519857e-01 0.000000e+00 0.0455420
 [9,] 2.468550e-02 8.339650e-02 1.038181e-01 1.575997e-01 0.0246855
[10,] 2.000000e+00 2.000000e+00 2.000000e+00 2.000000e+00 2.0000000
[11,] 3.000000e+00 3.000000e+00 3.000000e+00 3.000000e+00 3.0000000
[12,] 4.000000e+00 4.000000e+00 4.000000e+00 4.000000e+00 4.0000000
```

What I need is, if for each i repeat 3 times:

```
          p           X1 stations
1 0.1683427 5.940264e-01        2
2 0.4687956 0.9876516334        2
3 xxxxxxxx  xxxxxxxxxxxx        2
4 xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx        3
5 0.5533567 7.292506e-12        3
6 xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx        3
.................................
13 0.0500000 1.000000e+00       6
14 0.1683427 7.128317e-01       6
15 0.2321999 3.588861e-01       6
```

Comment: What format do you want the replicated result to be? That is, do you want to get that same output, but make it wider? If so, it would probably be easier to create separate matrices for p and psi, where each column is a separate replication, wouldn't it?

Comment: Actually you _can_ answer your own question. (There may be a time limit on how soon you can. It would be poor form to do so if David Robinson's answer were substantially correct. If it's not, then you should see if the necessary time has elapsed.)

Comment: believe I answered your 'replicate' question, edited my answer below.

Comment: Thank you all. I actually want to replicate each i n times and append the results to the data frame. Maybe that should be achieved by adding another for loop rather than replicate?

Comment: I know I can answer my own question but I had to wait 8 hrs. Couldn't wait that long..:P

Answer (score 5):

You cannot return a value multiple times- only the first return statement will occur, and the rest of the function will never run. Furthermore, you don't have brackets after your for loop, so the only line that is included in the for loop is:

```
for (i in 2:10)
    run.model<-mark(data[sample(nrow(data), i),], model="Occupancy")
```

This line thus runs 9 times, setting `run.model` to something different each time. Then the line:

```
results<-data.frame(mean(summary(run.model)$real$p), summary(run.model)$real$Psi, i)
return(results)
```

occurs only once. If you instead want to return a list with separate 9 data frames in it, you would do something more like:

```
foo<-function(data){
    lapply(2:10, function(i) {
        run.model<-mark(data[sample(nrow(data), i),], model="Occupancy")
        data.frame(mean(summary(run.model)$real$p), summary(run.model)$real$Psi)
    }
}
```

You could also combine that list into a single data frame (depending on how you want the data combined and returned). You could do that with `do.call` and `cbind`, though there are other solutions:

```
foo<-function(data){
    do.call(cbind, lapply(2:10, function(i) {
        run.model<-mark(data[sample(nrow(data), i),], model="Occupancy")
        cbind(mean(summary(run.model)$real$p), summary(run.model)$real$Psi)
    })
}
```

Comment: Cool, thanks! I modified your codes and will post it with the output.

Answer (score 3):

David Robinson's explanation is perfectly correct, but if you want to keep the explicit for loop rather than a lapply function, this should work:

```
foo<-function(data){
    results.frame <- data.frame()
    for (i in 2:10) {
        run.model<-mark(data[sample(nrow(data), i),], model="Occupancy")
        results<-data.frame(mean(summary(run.model)$real$p), summary(run.model)$real$Psi, i)          
        results.frame <- rbind(results.frame, results)
    }
    return(results.frame)
}
```

To answer the second question about replicate: the following should work, say you want to replicate the function 100 times, the following code will put each data.frame into a list of length 100:

```
replicate(100, foo(data))
```

if you want the results in a data frame:

```
replicate(100, foo(data), simplify="data.frame")
```

Not quite sure if the rows/columns will be preserved though.

Comment: Thanks so much. I modified your codes but since I can't answer my own question so I put in my original post.

Comment: I found the solution by simply adding another for loop in the beginning. :D